# Capture Attribute and Transfer Attribute nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

**1.** What is the difference between Capture Attribute and Transfer Attribute nodes?

**2.** How do different mapping modes in Transfer Attribute node work (Index, Nearest Face Interpolated, Nearest)?

**3.** What is an index here, and how this parameter affects Transfer Attribute node?

Answer (score 2):

I try to give a *very simplified* description or an explanation that is as short and understandable as possible:

First of all: An *attribute* can be many things. Basically it is mostly a certain numerical value of a certain type.

1. Capture Attribute

   Stores certain values for later use in the selected geometry. The data type of the value *(Float, Vector, Integer, etc.)* and to which part of the geometry it refers *(Points, Edges, Faces, etc.)* is defined.
2. Transfer Attributes

   Fetches the values of a specific element or area from a geometry/object. Here, another object is queried, so to speak, and data can be transferred in this way, as the name suggests.

   It is specified either whether a certain index of an element is to be queried here, or whether simply the nearest element of the specified domain *(Points, Edges, Faces, etc.)* is queried *(Nearest)*. In case of *Nearest Face Interpolated* anything in between will be returned.
3. Index

   Index is always a specific element of a domain *(Points, Edges, Faces, etc.)*. In the case of a cube, for example, you have eight elements of type *Points*, and six elements of type *Faces*.

Official Documentation:

- [Capture Attribute](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.1/modeling/geometry_nodes/attribute/capture_attribute.html)
- [Transfer Attribute](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.1/modeling/geometry_nodes/attribute/transfer_attribute.html)

> It is not easy to put something complicated into simple words, so please forgive me if this presentation looks incomplete or amateurish.

Comment: It's fine. Anyway, can you be more specific with the mapping types? I don't seem to get it. And are there examples of using indexes?

Comment: I tried to make this description as concise as possible and break it down to the essential points. I think for more detailed (and better) explanations the documentation is certainly more precise. Many examples of how to use indexes can be found here on blender.stackexchange.com. I would recommend to just click through the website and the variety of questions/answers, because there are so many use cases.

Comment: I am asking questions here because I don't understand Manual explanation sometimes.

Comment: Yes, I absolutely understand that. But please mind: I can't condense all relevant things about this topic into a few lines for you in such a way that they cover all possibilities and are understandable for a beginner at the same time. Maybe you expect a little bit much from me/us, because if it would be that easy, the people from Blender would have written their own documentation that way. So please forgive me for only having the opportunity (and time) here to refer to the multitude of wonderful entries on this website.